# TypeScript return same nested object structure but with different types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am working with this function which rebuilds the initial object, but casting every values to BigNumbers recursively.

```
export const castObjectValuesToBigNumber = function(initialObj: StringMap, nestedProp?: string) {

    let _castedObj: StringMap = {};

    for(const [property, value] of Object.entries(initialObj)) {

        if(typeof(value) === "object" && !(value instanceof BN)) {
            const newVal = castObjectValuesToBigNumber(value, property);
            _castedObj = { ..._castedObj, ...newVal };
        } else {
            if(nestedProp) {
                if(!_castedObj[nestedProp]) _castedObj[nestedProp] = {};
                _castedObj[nestedProp][property] = BigNumber.from(value.toString());
            } else {
                _castedObj[property] = BigNumber.from(value.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return _castedObj;
}
```

I would like to make it so that the return type is same as the `initialObj` type but with end values as BigNumber type.

Example:

```
const myValue = {
   propertyA: new BN(105),
   propertyB: {
      propertyC: new BN(1),
      propertyD: new BN(2),
      propertyE: new BN(3)
   },
   propertyF: {
      propertyG: new BN(4)
   }
}
```

I would like that if I put this value as a parameter of my function, typescript automatically returns this type:

```
{
   propertyA: BigNumber,
   propertyB: {
      propertyC: BigNumber,
      propertyD: BigNumber,
      propertyE: BigNumber
   },
   propertyF: {
      propertyG: BigNumber
   }
}
```

I tried lots of things with generics types and nested types but I always have an error of some type.

Here is a Minimum Reproducible Example:

```
/////////////////////
/// DECLARATIONS

interface StringMap { [key: string]: any }

class BN {
    value;
    constructor(num: number | string) {
        this.value = num;
    }

    _isBN() {
        return true;
    }
}

class BigNumber {
    value;
    constructor(num: number | string) {
        this.value = num;
    }

    _isBigNumber() {
        return true;
    }
}

const myValue = {
   propertyA: new BN(105),
   propertyB: {
      propertyC: new BN(1),
      propertyD: new BN(2),
      propertyE: new BN(3)
   },
   propertyF: {
      propertyG: new BN(4)
   }
};

/////////////////////
/// FUNCTION
export const castObjectValuesToBigNumber = function(initialObj: StringMap, nestedProp?: string) {

    let _castedObj: StringMap = {};

    for(const [property, value] of Object.entries(initialObj)) {

        if(typeof(value) === "object" && !(value instanceof BN)) {
            const newVal = castObjectValuesToBigNumber(value, property);
            _castedObj = { ..._castedObj, ...newVal };
        } else {
            if(nestedProp) {
                if(!_castedObj[nestedProp]) _castedObj[nestedProp] = {};
                _castedObj[nestedProp][property] = new BigNumber(value.toString());
            } else {
                _castedObj[property] = new BigNumber(value.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    return _castedObj;
}

/////////////////////
/// TEST

/*
    Result is of type StringMap while I would like it to be :

    {
        propertyA: BigNumber,
        propertyB: {
            propertyC: BigNumber,
            propertyD: BigNumber,
            propertyE: BigNumber
        },
        propertyF: {
            propertyG: BigNumber
        }
    }
    
*/

const myCastedValue = castObjectValuesToBigNumber(myValue);
```

Comment: What's `StringMap` and what's `BigNumber` and `BN`?  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?

Comment: StringMap is just any key value pair, BN is a big number instance of the bn.js package and BigNumber is also a big number instance but from another big number library which I prefer. I added the minimum reproducible example in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type we'll use to recursively change each `BN` to `BigNumber` could look like this:

```
type CastToBigNumber<T> = T extends BN ? BigNumber : {
    [K in keyof T]: CastToBigNumber<T[K]>
};
```

If `T` is a `BN`, then we change it to `BigNumber`, otherwise it's an object and we change all its properties.

The function definition now looks like this, using a generic parameter:

```
export const castObjectValuesToBigNumber = function<Initial extends StringMap>(initialObj: Initial, nestedProp?: string): CastToBigNumber<Initial> {
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WYZa3w)

Comment: That's amazing and really helping me understanding generics, thank you very much